# How to remove margin and padding from css table

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the spacing between the 2 rows.
The table is a css only table.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n841wvwn/

CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

div.table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

div.tr {
    display: table-row;
}

div.td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding:0; margin:0;
}

.button {
    width: 88px;
    height: 55px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}



#ac {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/u9znwQK.png');
    background-size: 100%;
}

#ce {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/azae5uQ.png');
    background-size: 100%;
}

#multiplication {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/veBf82o.png');
    background-size: 100%;
}


#division {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/i6KcXGr.png');
    background-size: 100%;
}


#number7 {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/0GixHJ5.png');
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="table" id="calculator">
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td" id="display"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">
                    <button class="button" id="ac"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <button class="button" id="ce"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <button class="button" id="division"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="td">
                    <button class="button" id="multiplication"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tr">
                <div class="td">
                    <button class="button" id="number7"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Between this circle I want no spacing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiJGo.png

The layout is based on a table div, which has table-layout fixed and display table. Also I have border-collapse set to collapse and every padding and margin to 0px.

For some reason the button is 55 px but the  div is 59 pixel in height.

Comment: Why you are not using table tag directly instead of using as a class?

Comment: Any reason why you want to use DIVs instead of table elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens only in Chrome and IE (not in Firefox, interesting...), and you can fix it on this way, too:

```
.button {
  display:block;
}
```

So, button is by default - *inline element* (and that's the cause of this small gap), and this way it will fill 100% height...

https://jsfiddle.net/n841wvwn/12/

Answer (score 4):

add `font-size:0;` as below :

```
div.td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding:0; margin:0;
  font-size:0;
}
```

This will solve your problem. But this will only work if u do not have any text inside the `td` element like in the case u showed.

Comment: Why? That's a great question.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, it is due to the `line-height` of the `table-cell`. You can explicitly set it to `0.8` to solve the problem:

```
div.td {
    line-height: 0.8;
}
```

Comment: 0.8 seems like a guess.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to all the solutions given, you can also align the buttons to the top of the table cells. That will work as well.

```css
.button {
  width: 88px;
  height: 55px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top; /* added */
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
div.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
div.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
div.td {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.button {
  width: 88px;
  height: 55px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: top; /* added */
}
#ac {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/u9znwQK.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}
#ce {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/azae5uQ.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}
#multiplication {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/veBf82o.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}
#division {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/i6KcXGr.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}
#number7 {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/0GixHJ5.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="table" id="calculator">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td" id="display"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">
        <button class="button" id="ac"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="td">
        <button class="button" id="ce"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="td">
        <button class="button" id="division"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="td">
        <button class="button" id="multiplication"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">
        <button class="button" id="number7"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Update your css as follows

```
 #number7 {
        background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/0GixHJ5.png');
        background-size: 100%;
            position:relative;
            top:-4px;
    }
```